# Programmatic override of high contrast color via Javascript

Tags: javascript, high-contrast

In short, can it be done?  What I'm seeing is that in any high contrast mode, any mouseover/hover event over an html5 button results in no color change (no indication that you've "caught" the button, and that a mouse click will actually activate it).  Is there any way to programmatically override a button background color when in high contrast mode, or does the browser lock you out of this in its overriding of colors and CSS content?  Thanks for any feedback on this.

Comment: Why can't you try transparency for the background color...??I mean when it is in contrast mode make it to 0 otherwise 1

Comment: In HC mode, the button bg is black, and the page bg is black... not sure transparency will help here.